# get federationmetadata xml from visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, adfs2.1

I'm new to MVC5, VS 2013 and ADFS.

Trying to connect a my app to a ADFS service.
I Have received the metadata document from ADFS but now they want the federationsmetadata XML from me.
They say that VS2013 should produce one.
I have no idea how to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to find out as well

Comment: Havent been able to produce it in 2013, used 2012 and Identity and access tool.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Identity and access tool for 2013 is EmbeddedSTS from Thinktecture.
Visit http://brockallen.com/2013/10/22/announcing-thinktecture-embeddedsts-a-simple-local-sts-for-asp-net-applications/

Comment: That's just a replacement for the LocalSTS that was included in the Identity and Access tool. It doesn't replace any of the configuration functionality that was also part of the I&A tool. The wizard used when creating a new ASP.NET Web App replaces some of the configuration functionality from the I&A tool, but as @kingRauk said, it doesn't create the FederationMetadata.xml file. If something exists that replaces that functionality from the I&A tool, I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Vittorio Bertocci (the Microsoft identity guru) has a pretty well hidden [blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/USE-THE-ON-PREMISES-ORGANIZATIONAL-AUTHENTICATION-OPTION-ADFS-WITH-ASP-NET-IN-VISUAL-STUDIO-2013/) walking you through connecting to ADFS with a VS2013 ASP.NET Web App.

Basically you set it up manually and do away with the whole FederationMetadata.xml side of things - which is fine by me!